# Colouring part of 3d text

Tags: materials, text-object

I desperately need to find out how to colour or shade part of 3D text in blender 2.8. I want to change A's and D's colour

**EDIT: It is text converted to mesh so this is ONE big object, and i cant ( i think) convert it back to 2d text becouse i lose progress. Also none of these soluttions works**

**EDIT: I cant change 2d text's colour as well ( i used mehtod shown linked below)**

[image]

[image]

Comment: you'll find an answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh